# is there a way to turn off "A append-to-register?

Tags: vim

from :help "A

"Vim fills these registers only when you say so.  Specify them as lowercase
  letters to replace their previous contents or as **uppercase letters to append
  to their previous contents**"

Is there a way to turn this off?

it's super annoying:  when I hold down shift to type double quote "  to append to a register, its pretty often the case I hold the shift for a split second too long and input "A instead of "a  (so it *appends* to register a instead of *replacing* it altogether)

Comment: This is probably hardcoded. You could probably map all the individual `"Xy` to `"xy` but it's certainly smarter to train your fingers more aggressively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to implement what @romainl has suggested it can be done in a six lines (three if you don’t mind having magic numbers, leaving unneeded variables and remapping in operator-pending mode):

```
let s:capshift=char2nr('A')-char2nr('a')
for s:ch in range(char2nr('A'), char2nr('B'))
    execute 'nnoremap "'.nr2char(s:ch).' "'.nr2char(s:ch-s:capshift)
    execute 'vnoremap "'.nr2char(s:ch).' "'.nr2char(s:ch-s:capshift)
endfor
unlet s:capshift s:ch
```

. But this solution has a drawback: you now loose ability to wait indefinitely between pressing `"` and `A` (unless you want to `set notimeout` which has problems on its own).

Answer (score 0):

i ended up writing a small patch which adds a "registerappend" option

...with this you can`:set noregisterappend` to disable it!

```
diff -r 4cb1f10316ca -r aedf9e836670 src/ops.c
--- a/src/ops.c Thu Oct 11 04:44:33 2012 +0200
+++ b/src/ops.c Tue Oct 16 01:28:47 2012 -0700
@@ -894,7 +894,8 @@ get_yank_register(regname, writing)
     else if (ASCII_ISUPPER(i))
     {
    i = CharOrdUp(i) + 10;
-   y_append = TRUE;
+   if(p_regappend)
+       y_append = TRUE;
     }
     else if (regname == '-')
    i = DELETION_REGISTER;
diff -r 4cb1f10316ca -r aedf9e836670 src/option.c
--- a/src/option.c  Thu Oct 11 04:44:33 2012 +0200
+++ b/src/option.c  Tue Oct 16 01:28:47 2012 -0700
@@ -2068,6 +2068,9 @@ static struct vimoption
                (char_u *)NULL, PV_NONE,
 #endif
                {(char_u *)2000L, (char_u *)0L} SCRIPTID_INIT},
+    {"registerappend", NULL,  P_BOOL,
+               (char_u *)&p_regappend, PV_NONE,
+               {(char_u *)TRUE, (char_u *)TRUE} SCRIPTID_INIT}, 
     {"relativenumber", "rnu", P_BOOL|P_VI_DEF|P_RWIN,
                (char_u *)VAR_WIN, PV_RNU,
                {(char_u *)FALSE, (char_u *)0L} SCRIPTID_INIT},
diff -r 4cb1f10316ca -r aedf9e836670 src/option.h
--- a/src/option.h  Thu Oct 11 04:44:33 2012 +0200
+++ b/src/option.h  Tue Oct 16 01:28:47 2012 -0700
@@ -495,6 +495,7 @@ EXTERN char_u   *p_popt;    /* 'printoptions'
 EXTERN char_u  *p_header;  /* 'printheader' */
 #endif
 EXTERN int p_prompt;   /* 'prompt' */
+EXTERN int p_regappend;    /* 'registerappend' */
 #ifdef FEAT_GUI
 EXTERN char_u  *p_guifont; /* 'guifont' */
 # ifdef FEAT_XFONTSET
```